# interactive plot with two parameters and interdependent data using ipywidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to create a jupyter-notebook cell showing an interactive plot with matplotlib to illustrate smoothing of a noisy signal. In the example below I am using the gaussian filter from scikit-image. I would like the level of the noise as well as the degree of smoothing to be adjustable by sliders. For this purpose I was using ipywidgets

Initially I tried the following

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage
%matplotlib inline

def plot_noise_filter(signal,cnts,sigma):
    s = signal/np.sum(signal)*cnts  #normalize the signal to have cnts counts
    noise = np.random.poisson(s)    #randomly generate poissonian noise
    filtered = skimage.filters.gaussian(noise,sigma)   #filter noisy signal with gauss filter
    f,ax = plt.subplots()                              #plot
    ax.plot(noise/np.max(noise))
    ax.plot(filtered/np.max(filtered))

c_slide = widgets.IntSlider(min=100,max=10000,step=10,description='counts')
s_slide = widgets.IntSlider(min=1,max=100,description='smoothing')

sig = np.heaviside(np.linspace(-1,1,100),1)+1
widgets.interact(plot_noise_filter,signal=widgets.fixed(sig),cnts=c_slide,sigma=s_slide)
```

In principle this gives me the desired plot but now each time I use the slider `s_slide`, the function is called and a new random signal is generated even though the counts have not changed. I would like the noisy signal in the plot to change only when the corresponding slider is moved.

The only workaround I could come up with, was to compute and store the noisy signals beforehand in an array and pick elements of that array according to the slider but this is not very elegant and may become very memory consuming.

My current installation is using conda and python 3.7.3

```
ipywidgets                7.5.1
matplotlib                3.1.1
jupyter                   1.0.0
jupyter_client            5.3.1
jupyter_console           6.0.0
jupyter_core              4.4.0
notebook                  6.0.1
numpy                     1.17.2
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thankyou for the very clear and runnable example.

How about extracting your signal and noise generating lines to a cached function using `lru_cache`? Then this part will always return the same value for the given `signal` and `cnts` input, leaving just the smoothing to change as you move that slider.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage
%matplotlib inline
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(32)
def make_sig_noise(signal, cnts):
    s = signal/np.sum(signal)*cnts  #normalize the signal to have cnts counts
    noise = np.random.poisson(s)    #randomly generate poissonian noise
    return s, noise

def plot_noise_filter(signal,cnts,sigma):
    s, noise = make_sig_noise(tuple(signal), cnts)
    filtered = skimage.filters.gaussian(noise,sigma)   #filter noisy signal with gauss filter
    f,ax = plt.subplots()                              #plot
    ax.plot(noise/np.max(noise))
    ax.plot(filtered/np.max(filtered))

c_slide = widgets.IntSlider(min=100,max=10000,step=10,description='counts')
s_slide = widgets.IntSlider(min=1,max=100,description='smoothing')

sig = np.heaviside(np.linspace(-1,1,100),1)+1
widgets.interact(plot_noise_filter,signal=widgets.fixed(sig),cnts=c_slide,sigma=s_slide)
```